# How to call the non Default constructor with assembly.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I need to call the Non default constructor when using assembly.CreateInstance. how?

Answer (score 27):

[`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) is a much friendlier API than `Assembly.CreateInstance` to use for these kinds of things:

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");
Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorParam1, constructorParam2);
```

Comment: You need to wrap the params into an Object[].

    `Activator.CreateInstance(type, new [] { constructorParam1, constructorParam2 });`

Comment: @Mark, no you don't.  It's a varargs method.

Comment: @Mark H - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(VS.71).aspx - `Function(params object[])` is a function taking 0 or more arguments.

Comment: @Matthew - it is a `params` methood; `varargs` is subtly different - you *can* use `varargs` from C# - but it is an undocumented keyword / compiler feature.

Comment: @Marc Gravell huh, didn't even know about those ones. For more info see this link: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030114.asp That's just so weird looking, very much like C vararg macros.

Comment: Oops, my mistake on the params arg. I've used CreateInstance many times and always wrapped the args in an object []. (It probably didn't show up in my intellisense the first time I use it.). It works the way I've been doing it, so I've always assumed it's been correct - didn't realise I was doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this overload:

```
public Object CreateInstance (
    string typeName,
    bool ignoreCase,
    BindingFlags bindingAttr,
    Binder binder,
    Object[] args,
    CultureInfo culture,
    Object[] activationAttributes
)
```

It has an `args` paramter.

Comment: What's the last parameter about? activationAttributes??

Comment: The last parameter is only useful for remoting scenarios. For example, you can specify a UrlAttribute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.activation.urlattribute.aspx).